# When using the TimeDim() function in Web-Intelligence, I get a multivalue error

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

I have a date-dimension which skips single days. I want to use the `TimeDim()` function to fill those days. The function fills the date successfully (e.g. where there are 3 days missing, it adds 3 new rows to the table), but instead of showing the actual dates, each row shows "multivalue error".

I should also hint that I display another dimension (ID-Number) alongside the dates, and that some days have multiple, different ID-values associated. Could this be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date dimension that you are using for TimeDim(), does it include a time component? I had a similar problem when I was using TimeDim() on an Oracle date field and I hadn't realized that having the same date portion, but different time portions, could throw off the results. Make sure your date field has no time portion, or you cast/truncate the field in the universe so it doesn't include any time portion.

Comment: The question is somewhat older, but I think this might have been the problem. Could I truncate/cast the field in the report itself to come to the same result? I didn't have access to the universe in this scenario.

Comment: Timedim() needs to operate on an actual universe object, not a report-level object, so unfortunately no. If you have access to a calendar table and it has a column that is defined something like `trunc(datefield)`, you may be able to join against that table and use that column instead of your regular datetime column.